# Android calendar content uri 2.3

Tags: android, calendar, uri, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm looking for the content uri for accessing the Android 2.3 calendars.

I've used this for my calendar apps up until now where:

```
Pre 2.1: "content://calendar/"
2.1 & 2.2: "content://com.android.calendar/"
2.3 : ???
```

I've recently upgraded my phone to 2.3 and to my shock and horror, I can't test my apps anymore and am at a stand still with development.

I've looked through all of the available content providers with no luck so if anyone has the string, please let me know.

(P.S. before someone tells me off about using something that's not part of the api, I've heard it all before)

Comment: What phone are you using? com.android.calendar works on my Samsung Galaxy S running 2.3.3.

Comment: I'm using a HTC Desire with CyanogenMod7. Maybe its the actual rom then...